# How to map tinyint to Integer in mysql and spring-boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I upgraded from `spring-boot-2.4.5` to `spring-boot-2.5.0`.

The issue occurs due to upgrade from `mariadb-java-client-2.7.2` to `mariadb-java-client-2.7.3`. But I don't know why, no do I know if this is more a hibernate or more a mariadb connector problem.

And now my application startup fails with:

`found [bit (Types#TINYINT)], but expecting [tinyint unsigned (Types#INTEGER)]`

I have declared the column as `@Column("TINYINT")` of type `Integer`, while in `mysql` it is a real `tinyint`, which worked without problems before the upgrade!

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
public Integer counter;
    
    
CREATE TABLE foo {
    ... 
    counter tinyint NOT NULL,
    ...
}
```

What could I do? Why is tinyint not supported anymore all of a sudden?

Full log:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [count] in table [foo]; found [bit (Types#TINYINT)], but expecting [tinyint unsigned (Types#INTEGER)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to this :

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.IntegerType")
public Integer counter;
```

Comment: Same error: `[bit (Types#TINYINT)], but expecting [tinyint(1) unsigned (Types#INTEGER)]`

Comment: @membersound I have updated my answer. Just check if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately not: `found [bit (Types#TINYINT)], but expecting [tinyint(1) unsigned (Types#INTEGER)]`

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem now with spring boot 3.1.1. My definitions of `TINYINT UNSIGNED` & `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` stopped working. I resolved it by changing definitions to `TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED` & `SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED`, which sets the display width of the columns and has nothing to do with value ranges. More can be found [in official mysql 8 doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

Please let me know, if someone else has the same problem or knows the reason for this! Not a fan of specifying this for every single column...